# How to setup Lightning Node on Windows Desktop in 2022?

Tags: lightning-network, full-node, lightning-network-daemon, windows

I have gone through setting up lightning node, but a lot of resources stated to get hardware and to run LND through command line. But How can we setup a Lightning node in regular laptop with nice GUI and nice features without any hardware?

Answer (score 0):

LND provides binaries for Windows and you can use a GUI-based web app such as Ride-The-Lightning (RTL). They provide fairly comprehensive documentation to get started: https://dev.lightning.community/tutorial/

I also wrote a tutorial, which has been updated for 2022: https://medium.com/@johnny_pham/guide-setup-a-lightning-network-node-on-windows-8475206807f

It uses command line but I mention RTL at the end. The RTL GitHub repository provides easy installation instructions.